# Dropbox API request pattern

Tags: ios, synchronization, dropbox

I am using the Dropbox SDK on iOS, and am mirroring a remote directory locally. I understand the basic usage pattern - make a request, wait for the delegate to be called with the results.

When I have a large number of requests to perform, should I serialize them by waiting for the result before making the next call, or make all requests at once and then just wait for them each to come in? Does the Dropbox SDK handle the latter case intelligently (e.g. with an `NSOperationQueue`), or am I better off doing this myself?

If I am better off handling request queuing myself, should I change behavior when the user is on a wifi vs. cellular connection?

EDIT: I have seen [CHBgDropboxSync](https://github.com/chrishulbert/CHBgDropboxSync) and other existing solutions. My app requires more control over syncing than these provide, so I need to roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many requests you need to make and how reliant they are on each other. With either GCD or `NSOperation` you can daisy-chain requests, you can issue them all at once and keep semaphores in your program, or you can make requests rely on others to complete. You're creating an asynchronous state machine, and its design will depend on whether that state machine is dynamic or static.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question though. I'm asking about in the context of the Dropbox API specifically; does it do any request queuing itself, or will it blindly issue all requests at once?